# How to remove a cell containing an underscore or a period in R?

Tags: r, regex

I have character strings such as "76.1" and "76.1_0". I'd like to remove all elements of my dataframe that contain either a "." or a "_".

I've tried

```
df <- df[!grepl("_", "."),]
```

which didn't work. I know it's my regex that's the issue but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an example vector

```
(x <- c("76.1", "76.1_0", "1", "a"))
# [1] "76.1"   "76.1_0" "1"      "a"
```

one gets the desired result with, e.g.,

```
(x <- x[!grepl("\\.|_", x)])
# [1] "1" "a"
```

where I used `grepl` differently in a couple of aspects

1) The first argument, `pattern`, has to be a character string (`"\\.|_"`) rather than multiple arguments, as you tried (`"_", "."`). See `?grepl`.

2) As to "combine" two symbols, one needs to use `|`, which stands for [OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts).

3) `.` is a special character and needs to be [escaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax) with `\\`.

4) You didn't provide the second argument, `x`; i.e., where the changes should be done.